# How do I convert a vhd to a wim file?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, hyper-v, dism

I just setup and sysprepped a nice new VM, now I need to convert it to a wim real quick, to upload to my sccm server. For some reason, I can't change the VM properties to boot from a legacy nic for pxe, which is how I usually capture my images using sccm. VMM just changes the settings right back, even though it says successful.

Anyway, the first page of google was *terrible* for this, w/ the exception of a 3rd party .ps1 script on MS's website, but I'm using 2012r2, I should be able to do this natively, right?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Absolutely, let's post a prim and proper answer for Google. This is a simple 2 command Powershell execution, using the `dism` module. The dism can be copied to earlier versions of Windows, provided you have the appropriate version of the windows management framework.

First, mount the vhd using

```
Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath C:\VHDs\BigHomies.vhdx -Path C:\VHDMount -Index 1
```

Then, capture it into a wim with

```
New-WindowsImage -CapturePath C:\VHDMount -Name Win7Image -ImagePath C:\CapturedWIMs\Win7.wim -Description "Yet another Windows 7 Image" -Verify
```

And let it do it's thing. When you are done you can unmount the vhd and discard any changes using:

```
Dismount-WindowsImage -Path C:\VHDMount -Discard
```

Comment: Correction to the second command: -ImagePath should specify the full path to the WIM file (e.g. C:\CapturedWIMs\NewWinImage.wim), while -Name is the name of the image inside the WIM file (e.g. NewWinImage, but has no actual relation to the WIM file name).
Executing the originally posted command results in "New-WindowsImage: Access is denied." (presumably because the command attempts to treat the C:\CapturedWIMs directory as a file).

Comment: Interesting analysis, [technet's example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376479.aspx) also seems to agree with you. I'll update it, even though I ripped this *straight* from my powershell prompt lol.

Comment: +1 this answer really helped me out!

Comment: Be sure to run the x64 version of powershell (if on x64 windows) and run with administrator privileges. Failing to do either of those will result in various errors. See http://serverfault.com/questions/700839/new-windowsimage-stalls-with-0x8007007e-cant-load-unattend-dll/807578#807578

Comment: I got access denied, if anyone can help. I tried to mount with disk management as well. I am using 64 version and with administrator privileges, still the error comes from the second command.

Comment: @ClearBoth on the `New-WindowsImage` command? I wonder if the vhdx is in use, or otherwise cannot be locked.

Comment: So, if your VHD is separated into multiple partitions, how do you get those to implement properly within the WIM file?

Comment: I know this answer is a few years old, but as far as I can tell, the process hasn't changed much... however I have had an issue with the above I felt it was useful to share, as I couldn't find google hits for the issue. 

Doing the above works fine, but I've had an issue where the c: drive permissions on a machine built with SCCM matched the permissions of the folder you've used to mount the image, rather than the permissions the VHDX had originally. The solution seems to be to mount the vhdx to a drive, instead of in a folder.

Answer (score 3):

If, for some reason, Powershell is not an option - do not despair!

In Windows 7 or later, you can mount the .vhd via disk management ([link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/11/09/how_2d00_to_2d00_mount_2d00_vhd_2d00_image_2d00_from_2d00_windows_2d00_7_2d00_step_2d00_by_2d00_step_2d00_without_2d00_any_2d00_third_2d00_party_2d00_toolsthe_2d00_easy_2d00_way.aspx))

Once it is mounted, you can use imagex.exe to capture the .wim ([technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749003(v=ws.10).aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Same method as the accepted answer, but without the need for PowerShell

```
dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\Backup.vhdx /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\Mount
dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:C:\Backup.wim /CaptureDir:C:\Mount /Name:Backup
Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\Mount /Discard
```